# Replacing the values in a column in select query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table where one of the columns is ids as foreign key to another table. how can I replace the ids with data from the other table inside select query?

Comment: Please add sample data and table structure, along with your current code.

Answer (score 1):

You use a join:

```
select t1.column_one, t2.display_value
from table_one t1
  join table_two t2 on t1.fk_column_to_table_two = t2.primary_key_column;
```